# Creating Windows authentication and SQL Server authentication in login form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, authentication, ssms

I have a login form in Visual Studio C# and below is a screenshot of it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uziUD.png

My goal is to allow the user to choose whether to log in using Windows authentication, in a workplace as we are using LAN network or using SQL Server authentication (username and password are stored in server -> security -> login).

Below is the code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Login_HouseKeeping_
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Connection string
        string cs = @"Data Source = 172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2; Initial catalog =GCVS2_DEV_GHR; Integrated Security = True;";

        // Login click event
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide Username and Password");
                return;
            }
            else
                try
                {
                    //Create sqlconnection
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE Username = @username AND Password = @Password", con);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);

                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapt.Fill(ds);

                    con.Close();

                    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                    // if count equals to 1, then show frmMain form
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login successful");
                        this.Hide();

                        frmMain fm = new frmMain();
                        fm.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
                    }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find many resources on implementing these two authentication into my login. How do I achieve this?

EDIT:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            var connStrBldr = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connStrBldr.DataSource = "172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2";
            connStrBldr.InitialCatalog = "GCVS2_DEV_GHR";
            if (WindowsAuth)
            {
                connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            }
            else
            {
                connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                connStrBldr.UserID = textBox1.Text;
                connStrBldr.Password = textBox2.Text;
            }
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrBldr.ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                //do your lookup on login here
            }







        }

        private void WindowsAuth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void SqlAuth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is I can't figure out how to have windows authentication and sql server authentication in my login.

Comment: Windows authentication for your active directory?

Comment: Yup that's correct

Comment: Do i need to always reference login credentials to my own database?

Comment: Do you want to have a specified db user to perform transactions to your database or should that db user depend on the one the logged-in? What happens if the user exists in the active directory but has no access to the database?

Comment: Actually this is the situation: This whole program is for workplace. So since all the computers in workplace are connected via LAN network. So, if I want to login via windows auth, I have to use my credentials associated with my computer. I cannot use other colleague's credential to login using my computer but they can login in their own computer using their own credentials. That's about it.

Comment: For sql auth, I believe it works the same way as windows? They have to create their own sql login in sql server?

Comment: Yes it should be that db user depend on the one that logged in. I am not quite sure if the user exists in active directory but has no access to database but everyone in my team has access to that server/database so I guess it's not an issue?

Comment: @Tim 's answer is the one you need. All you have to do is disable the username and password text boxes if windows authentication is selected. Have you tried it out yet?

Comment: I have to figure out how to link the radio button clicked respectively to link it with the login mode. In my If statement, they do not accept WindowsAuth as bool value. Do i have to reference it to something else?

Comment: The issue is under  connStrBldr.DataSource = "172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2";   , I have an error on the slash \ as it says unrecognize escape sequence. But that is the name of my data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only posting this answer since OP can't seem to make @Tim's answer work. Credits to @Tim.

Just simply use:

EDIT: Changed since username and password is not mandatory for windows authentication.

```
private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool useWindowsAuth = WindowsAuth.Checked; // Assuming that WindowsAuth is your radio button

    string userName = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;

    if(!useWindowsAuth)
    {
        userName = textBox1.Text;
        password = textBox2.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide Username and Password");
            return;
        }
    }

    var connStrBldr = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connStrBldr.DataSource = @"172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2";
    connStrBldr.InitialCatalog = "GCVS2_DEV_GHR";

    if (useWindowsAuth) 
    {
        connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        connStrBldr.UserID = userName;
        connStrBldr.Password = password;
    }

    bool validUser = true;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrBldr.ToString())) 
        {
            con.Open();
            //do your lookup on login here
        }
    }
    catch(SqlException) // An exception will be caught if invalid credentials were used.
    {
        validUser = false;
    }

    if(validUser)
        MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Login failed!");    
    }
}
```

I have verified that the code works using a sample project. You just have to make sure of the following:

1. Username and Password is correct (Server > Security).
2. User has access to `GCVS2_DEV_GHR` table. This can be configured under (Server > Security > User)

Also, this way of coding is not a good way to do it but since you seem new to C# just make sure to study more about good practices.

Comment: Did you mean it works on your computer ? You can login using both modes of authentication?

Comment: Okay I tried your code, it works but I have a question, if i want to login via windows authentication, do i have to enter username and password and login or just leave them blank?

Comment: just leave them blank. It's not needed since `IntegratedSecurity` is set to `true`

Comment: I marked your answer as solved. I could login via sql auth using the credentials in sql login i already created. Do I still need to do lookup on login ? I'm confused

Comment: No need to look up on the login. As long as you were able to open the `SqlConnection` then that means that the user is valid.

Comment: How come login in using windows auth, we leave it blank?  Isn't it better say my windows auth username : xyz and pass: 111 and i have to use that credential to login via windows auth. Then, my colleague has credentials username: abcd,pass:222 and he has to use it to login via windows auth.

Comment: Hmmmm, when I clicked on windows auth mode and leave credentials blank, it would say "please provide username and password" instead of login successful.

Comment: Actually this depends on what you want. Current design (answer above) limits the windows authentication user to the currently logged-in user in windows. If you still want to define the user for windows authentication then you will need to do impersonation. The answer would be a bit long so I would recommend reading [Active Directory user impersonation with C#](https://ehikioya.com/active-directory-user-impersonation/). This is to be done anywhere before you call `con.Open()`. The goal of this would be tricking the app that you are a different user than the currently logged-in user in windows.

Comment: I see. What about the current answer above where you can't login via windows auth if u leave textbox blank?

Comment: see updated answer. I changed `if(useWindowsAuth)` to `if(!useWindowsAuth)`. Should work properly now.

Comment: This is a complex case if i think about it. Because my work computer is associated to my windows credentials and thus, I have to use my own credential to login via windows auth to validate my credentials,  I can't use my colleagues credentials. My colleague has to use his computer with his windows credentials and login in the same way in his computer using his credential. If that makes sense.

Comment: If there's only one user per computer (Windows Authentication) then no need to do impersonation. The code above is enough for your requirement.

Comment: What if i really want to users to enter their credentials using windows auth linked to their own computer, are there any resources on this? Or is that a different situation all together?

Comment: Then you'd have to require the username and password. You'd also have to perform impersonation as stated in my previous comments.

Comment: Do you have any resources of auto generating activity log ? For example, once I successfully logged into the program (regardless of either mode), a save dialog appears for me to save a log file ( to name whatever i want) . The activity log basically tracks pretty much everything that is done(has timeline as well) in the program after login in. So if there's any error in the future, I can trace the error using the log easier. I am new to this area so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Check out [How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file). This is a basic way of file accessing (read/write). You can search SO and google for more and better examples. But remember that there is no auto code generation for us programmers. We have to **program** the software to do it for us.

Comment: Should i work on whatever after the login page first or work on the impersonation for windows authen?

Comment: Is there any line of communication to communicate with you rather than here? Because I don't wanna spam this thread so much and I always love to learn more knowledge from other .net developers, that is if you don't mind.

Comment: @CookieMan personally since you've got the login working already, I won't bother with the impersonation right away. Work on the real purpose of your application. Also, almost every programming resource you need is on the web. Utilize it. If you stumble upon something that you consider a very difficult roadblock then you may ask us the SO community. Just make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Try things out yourself and share your code. We encourage you to think through your problem before we extend our help.

Comment: Would it be better to work on the auto generated log file right after login in or on the functionalities of the program? The functionalities of the program is to have functions to execute sql scripts ( to count number of rows, check if new table has same rows as old table,etc ).

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is controlled by your connection string.  Your best bet is to use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to build the connection string dynamically based on whether you want SQL Server auth or Windows auth:

```
var connStrBldr = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connStrBldr.DataSource = "172.28.40.19\CASINO2008R2";
connStrBldr.InitialCatalog = "GCVS2_DEV_GHR";
if (useWindowsAuth) {
    connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
} else {
    connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = false;
    connStrBldr.UserID = textBox1.Text;
    connStrBldr.Password = textBox2.Text;
}
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrBldr.ToString())) {
    con.Open();
    //do your lookup on login here
}
```

Comment: So what this does is it allow user to choose windows auth and proceed to login with their credentials or choose sql server auth and login with credentials login stored on sql server?

Comment: What if the user wants to do windows authentication (Active Directory) with the credentials of another user? Doesn't this approach limits your credentials to that of the currently logged-on user?

Comment: When you set `IntegratedSecurity=false`, it means that it will use SQL Server's authentication, which is handled entirely by sql server, not maintained by your `LOGIN` table.  Use `CREATE LOGIN` to manage the logins for SQL Server authentication.

Comment: @John Ephraim Tugado, to do windows authentication as another user, you must first impersonate the other user for your process by p/invoking the windows api.  My example merely illustrates how to dynamically connect using either windows auth or sql auth based on a run-time choice.

Comment: I already have a Login in sql server. Under "if (useWindowsAuth)" , where does that convention reference to?

Comment: So i can delete my old section for // create sql connection?